# Amazon SNS Mobile Push to sub set of devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Is it possible to push messages to a subset of the app installs with SNS.

When publishing to a topic by default all subscribers get the notification.

Answer (score 3):

As you mention, when publishing to a topic, all (valid) endpoints that are subscribed receive the message.   There's no conditional operations here - it's all or nothing.

Your options for sending to a smaller subset are:

1. Maintain a number of SNS topics that group the users together the way you want.  This requires subscribing and unsubscribing endpoints to your topics from your own code.
2. You can send directly specific endpoints from your own code, using the [Publish API Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/APIReference/API_Publish.html).  You would specify an endpointArn for the `TargetArn` property, and do not specify a value for the `TopicArn` property.  You would need to manage these groupings of endpoints in your code and simply loop through each desired recipient and publish to its endpoint.